# Обьясните, пожалуйста суть задания по моделям Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Задание по Django Rest Framework, Нужно создать сервер авторизации и новостей.

К заданию пояснение, что должна быть модель Users (имя пользователя, пароль в зашифрованном виде).
Я не понимаю мне нужно создать самому эту модель, тогда какое поле использовать для пароля?
Или имееться ввиду, использовать встроенный класс User?

Разьясните пожалуйста.